# How to conditionally fill a cell based on the value of another cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, conditional-statements

I want to fill the NaN cell values of the column “SaleTypeName" with the word “valid” for rows where the ProductName has the value Salad.

So far I came this far:
sales['SaleTypeName'].fillna("Valid", inplace=True)
But I am missing a conditional aspect here so that not the entire column is filled when NaN appears

I have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame ({'Flight Day': ['2018-10-01', '2018-10-01','2018-10-01', '2018-10-01', '2018-10-02','2018-10-02', '2018-10-02', '2018-10-02', '2018-10-03','2018-10-03’, '2018-10-03','2018-10-03’],'Flight Number': [LX1336, LX1337, LX1472, LX1473, LX1336, LX1337, LX1472, LX1473, LX1336, LX1337, LX1472, LX1473],'STD Departure': [10, 15, 8, 11,10, 15, 8, 14,10, 15, 8, 11], ‘Quantity': [2, NaN, 8, 4,3, 2, 3, 1,NaN, 5, 2, 1],’ProductName': [Bircher, Salad, Carac, Salad, Bircher, Carac, Carac, Salad,Bircher, Carac, Carac, Salad], 'SaleTypeName': [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN ,NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]})
```

Comment: Please paste your code correctly. The code that you provided has many error. I couldn't initialize the df.

Comment: try `df.loc[df['A'] == 'foo']['SaleTypeName'].fillna("Valid", inplace=True)`

Comment: It is good that you have given code for creating the df but it refers to many names that don't exist in your code. In order for us to even create the df we have to go through and convert everything to strings before we can even try to address the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
df.SaleTypeName.mask(df.ProductName=='Salad', 'Valid', inplace=True)
```

`mask()` function is used to select the rows with `ProductName` as `"Salad"` in `SaleTypeName` column whose values are replaced with `"Valid"`.

`inplace` argument is used to make the changes in the original dataframe itself.

See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html).

Answer (score 0):

For this particular problem, you can try out this code and later on you can modify accordingly.

DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame (
    {'Flight Day': ['2018-10-01', '2018-10-01','2018-10-01', '2018-10-01', '2018-10-02','2018-10-02', '2018-10-02', '2018-10-02', '2018-10-03','2018-10-03', '2018-10-03','2018-10-03'],
     'Flight Number': ['LX1336', 'LX1337', 'LX1472', 'LX1473', 'LX1336', 'LX1337', 'LX1472', 'LX1473', 'LX1336', 'LX1337', 'LX1472', 'LX1473'],
     'STD Departure': [10, 15, 8, 11,10, 15, 8, 14,10, 15, 8, 11],
     'Quantity': [2, np.NaN, 8, 4,3, 2, 3, 1,np.NaN, 5, 2, 1],
     'ProductName': ['Bircher',' Salad',' Carac',' Salad',' Bircher',' Carac',' Carac',' Salad','Bircher',' Carac',' Carac',' Salad'],
     'SaleTypeName': [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN ,np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN]})
```

Code part to implement:

```
def replace(name):
    return "valid" if name.strip()=="Salad" else np.NaN

df['SaleTypeName'] = df.loc[:,'ProductName'].apply(lambda x: replace(x))
```

Output:

```
    ProductName SaleTypeName
0      Bircher          NaN
1        Salad        valid
2        Carac          NaN
3        Salad        valid
4      Bircher          NaN
5        Carac          NaN
6        Carac          NaN
7        Salad        valid
8      Bircher          NaN
9        Carac          NaN
10       Carac          NaN
11       Salad        valid
```